# SensorEvent.timestamp date conversion issue

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm trying to convert event timestamp in a date, my code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(event.timestamp/1000000);//time in ms (timestamp is in ns)
System.out.println((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")).format(c.getTime()));
```

How come I get 1970-01-02?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are using [SensorEvent.timestamp](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#timestamp). The documentation fails to mention that this is the awake time in nanoseconds since the last boot (comparable to [SystemClock.uptimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29)), not time since Unix epoch. In short, it appears your device has been awake for less than two days.

Also, `Calendar.getTime()` returns a Date object and there is a Date constructor that takes milliseconds so  you can shorten your code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date(event.timestamp / 1000000)));
```

Comment: And I can't obtain current time from sensor timestamp?

Comment: You could call `System.currentTimeMillis()` when you get the event in `onSensorChanged()` and that would give you the event time (within a couple milliseconds) or you could try to find the time of the last boot and add the event time to it. (Understand that a `long` is too small hold nanoseconds since epoch.)